# Square returning error with WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, plugins, woocommerce, square-connect

I've installed the WooCommerce Square plugin to enable payments to our Square account but I get this error at the checkout when trying to pay with a credit card:

```
Array(
  [0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [category] => INVALID_REQUEST_ERROR
        [code] => MISSING_REQUIRED_PARAMETER
        [detail] => Missing required parameter.
        [field] => card_nonce
    )
)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Ok thank Aleh, I will try but I'm not a developer at all. I don't know code at all. That is why I have no idea what this means.

Comment: It tells you that your request should contain additional parameter `[detail] => Missing required parameter.` and its name is `[field] => card_nonce`. So you have to check why it is not sent or how it should be sent.

Comment: Since the asker is using the WooCommerce square plugin, the fact it is erroring out might not be their problem.....  seriously, what is wrong with you?